# How to share Single Mac OS X Application for remote desktop

Tags: macos, mac, windows, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

Scenario: I have a Mac mini which is always on always connected to internet. I want to share **Single application** (let's say XCode).

By sharing means remotely use it via remote desktop on Windows. It should be shared in such a way that Mac user uses something else and Remotely somebody else is using XCode.

Question: Is it possible? If yes, then how?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use "Screen Sharing".

[image]

Open "System Preferences" and select "Sharing". Now click the lock at bottom left to allow changes. You will be asked for your password.

Now click on "Screen Sharing". On the right you can now click on "Computer Settings..." Select "VNC Viewers may control screen with password and enter a password in the box. Click on "OK" and quit from "System Preferences".

You will now be able to use a VNC client on  your PC to control the Mac. This will not allow two people to use the computer at the same time.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. This would share the entire Mac, and not just a single application - also it wouldn't allow two people to use the computer at the same time, as you mention.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue of sharing a single application. It should be something like RDP with a Window's server application